# Checkmarx plugin in SonarQube 5.6.4

Tags: sonarqube, checkmarx

What is the version of Checkmarx plugin that can be used in SonarQube 5.6.4?

We face issues in **Checkmarx Widget Configuration**, where we get the error `Connection to Checkmarx server failed`.

Any suggestions to make this work?  We get this error when using 8.2 and 7.2.2.5 
 of the Checkmarx plugin.

Comment: The plugin does not work when using oracle database but works standalone.   The error got when using with oracle database is as follows

Comment: 2017.01.10 08:19:13 INFO  web[c.c.s.CxValidator] CxValidator instance created
2017.01.10 08:19:13 WARN  web[c.c.sonar.CxConnect] Connection to Checkmarx server failed: 2 counts of InaccessibleWSDLException.

Comment: Hi, activate anonymous connection on IIS for CxWebInterface may fix the issue, but it's not a real solution !

Answer (score 0):

check out: http://download.checkmarx.com/8.2.0/Plugins/CxSonarPlugin-8.2.0.zip

the download link is available from: https://www.checkmarx.com/plugins/

Comment: Did this work for you? if so, please accept the response

Comment: The above checkmarx plugin(8.2) does not work when used with 5.6.4 version Sonar and Oracle database